# Writing Python Dictionary to MySQL with multiple values per key

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to write a python dictionary to MySQL that has multiple values per key, trying to use something similar to this:

```
placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(myDict))
columns = ', '.join(myDict.keys())
sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % (table, columns, placeholders)
# valid in Python 2
cursor.execute(sql, myDict.values())
# valid in Python 3
cursor.execute(sql, list(myDict.values()))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./grabber.py", line 86, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, list(relay_stats.values()))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
server01 (0.0, 0.0, '2020-07-07 15:01:54')
server02 (0.0, 0.0, '2020-07-07 15:01:54')
server03 (0.0, 0.0, '2020-07-07 15:01:54')
server04 (0.0, 0.0, '2020-07-07 15:01:54')
```

MySQL Table:

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| server_name | char(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| file_count  | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| file_size   | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| curtime     | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How can I insert this so each value is a column in the database, while keeping the 0.0 values as integers?

Comment: Can you share the table structure?

Comment: It might not be the best layout, but I used this to create:

CREATE TABLE stats(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,server_name CHAR,file_count float,file_size float,curtime datetime,PRIMARY KEY ( ID ) );


Ideally it would have 4 columns, server name, file count, file size, and datetime

Comment: Does your dictionary look like this: `{'server01': (0.0, 0.0, '2020-07-07 15:01:54')...}`? That is, the server name is the key, and the other part is the value?

Comment: Yes, the server name is the key, and the other 3 parts are the value, made from another dictionary using this:

`dict = {}
for key, value in sorted(servers.items()):
    dict[key] = (fc_grab(value), fs_grab(value), curtime)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather  than creating another dict, create a list of tuples containing the values:

```py
values = []
for key, value in sorted(servers.items()):
    values.append((key, fc_grab(value), fs_grab(value), curtime))
```

Now you can create your SQL

```
placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(values[0]))
columns = ', '.join(['server_name', 'file_count', 'file_size', 'curtime'])
sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % (table, columns, placeholders)
cursor.executemany(sql, values)
```

`cursor.executemany` inserts all the rows in a single python method call, rather than doing `cursor.execute` in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the info, the only issue I have is how do I specify the table name?  I've tried replacing the %s and the table variable but get `    sql = "INSERT INTO filldbstats ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % (table, columns, placeholders)
NameError: name 'table' is not defined
'

Comment: I was able to specify the table ahead of the sql insert statement by doing table = 'stats'  I don't get any errors, but it's not inserting any data into the DB

Comment: Have you calledthe _connection's_ `commit()` method?

Comment: That was my problem, forgot to commit.  Thanks!